# Killing multi-threaded SocketServer

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, kill

I'm trying to figure out why I can't kill my multi threaded SocketServer via a CRTL-C.

Basically I have that :

```
import SocketServer,threading

class TEST(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def server_bind(self):
        self.socket.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,SO_REUSEPORT, 1)
        self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
        self.socket.setblocking(0)

    def handle(self):
        request, socket = self.request
        data = request
        if data[0] == "\x01":
           buff = "blablabla"
           socket.sendto(str(buff), self.client_address)

class TEST1(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def server_bind(self):
        self.socket.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,SO_REUSEPORT, 1)
        self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
        self.socket.setblocking(0)

    def handle(self):
        request, socket = self.request
        data = request
        if data[0] == "\x01":
           buff = "blablabla"
           socket.sendto(str(buff), self.client_address)

class TEST2(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def server_bind(self):
        self.socket.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,SO_REUSEPORT, 1)
        self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
        self.socket.setblocking(0)

    def handle(self):
        request, socket = self.request
        data = request
        if data[0] == "\x01":
           buff = "blablabla"
           socket.sendto(str(buff), self.client_address)

class TEST3(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def server_bind(self):
        self.socket.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,SO_REUSEPORT, 1)
        self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
        self.socket.setblocking(0)

    def handle(self):
        request, socket = self.request
        data = request
        if data[0] == "\x01":
           buff = "blablabla"
           socket.sendto(str(buff), self.client_address)

def serve_thread_udp(host, port, handler):
    server = SocketServer.UDPServer((host, port), handler)
    server.serve_forever()

def serve_thread_tcp(host, port, handler):
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((host, port), handler)
    server.serve_forever()

def main():
    try:
      threading.Thread(target=serve_thread_tcp,args=('', 4045,TEST)).start()
      threading.Thread(target=serve_thread_tcp,args=('', 239,TEST1)).start()
      threading.Thread(target=serve_thread_udp,args=('', 1246,TEST2)).start()
      threading.Thread(target=serve_thread_tcp,args=('', 12342,TEST3)).start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        os._exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except:
        raise
```

I'm trying to understand what i've done wrong and what would be the best way to be able to kill the whole script via a crtl-c.
Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you have four identical classes? Also, you won't be able to listen to port `239` without special permissions.

Comment: The concept is to bind 4 ports and try to kill the server with a crtl-c.

Comment: You can still use the same request handler class for all ports, no need to create a _separate class_ for each port, unless they do different things (which you don't).

Comment: There is 7 servers like that, that answers to different queries on different ports.

Comment: Take a look at the `signal` module. You will be able to catch SIGINT and react appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
def main():
    import thread
    try:
      thread.start_new(serve_thread_tcp, ('', 4045,TEST))
      thread.start_new(serve_thread_tcp,('', 239,TEST1))
      thread.start_new(serve_thread_udp,('', 1246,TEST2))
      thread.start_new(serve_thread_tcp,('', 12342,TEST3))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        os._exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except:
        raise
    raw_input()
```

To close the server you can type return or close the stdin.

The Problem is with the `Thread` class that will not allow closing the application before all `Threads` are closed.

serve_forever() will not end until you close the belonging to server(an other solution) on KeyboardInterrupt.

Comment: a friend told me you could also use `Thread.setDeamon(..., True)` to avoid the closing issue.

Answer (score 1):

When creating threads, set them as daemon :

```
Thread.__init__(self)
self.setDaemon(True)
```

In this way all the thread will terminate when you have killed the main thread.

Based on python documentation in [here](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#thread-objects) :

> A thread can be flagged as a “daemon thread”. The significance of this flag is that the entire Python program exits when only daemon threads are left. The initial value is inherited from the creating thread. The flag can be set through the daemon property.